# Unexpected use of 'self' no-restricted-globals

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a React app. And the app works great but when I include the following javascript file the compilating fails and I've got the following error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/recorder.js
>
> Line 1:    'define' is not defined   no-undef
>
> Line 1:    Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals    Line 1: 
>   Unexpected use of'self'  no-restricted-globals Line 355:  Unexpected
>   use of 'self' no-restricted-globals   Line 355:  Unexpected use of
>   'self'  no-restricted-globals
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.L

I am not quite sure what could be the problem, I've attached the code of this file.

```
(function(f) {
    if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module !== "undefined") {
        module.exports = f()
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([], f)
    } else {
        var g;
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            g = window
        } else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
            g = global
        } else if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
            g = self
        } else {
            g = this
        }
        g.Recorder = f()
    }
})(function() {
    var define, module, exports;
    return (function e(t, n, r) {
        function s(o, u) {
            if (!n[o]) {
                if (!t[o]) {
                    var a = typeof require == "function" && require;
                    if (!u && a) return a(o, !0);
                    if (i) return i(o, !0);
                    var f = new Error("Cannot find module '" + o + "'");
                    throw f.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", f
                }
                var l = n[o] = {
                    exports: {}
                };
                t[o][0].call(l.exports, function(e) {
                    var n = t[o][1][e];
                    return s(n ? n : e)
                }, l, l.exports, e, t, n, r)
            }
            return n[o].exports
        }
        var i = typeof require == "function" && require;
        for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) s(r[o]);
        return s
    })({
        1: [function(require, module, exports) {
            "use strict";

            module.exports = require("./recorder").Recorder;

        }, {
            "./recorder": 2
        }],
        2: [function(require, module, exports) {
            'use strict';

            var _createClass = (function() {
                function defineProperties(target, props) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
                        var descriptor = props[i];
                        descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
                        descriptor.configurable = true;
                        if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
                        Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
                    }
                }
                return function(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
                    if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
                    if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
                    return Constructor;
                };
            })();

            Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
                value: true
            });
            exports.Recorder = undefined;

            var _inlineWorker = require('inline-worker');

            var _inlineWorker2 = _interopRequireDefault(_inlineWorker);

            function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
                return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
                    default: obj
                };
            }

            function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
                if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
                    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
                }
            }

            var Recorder = exports.Recorder = (function() {
                function Recorder(source, cfg) {
                    var _this = this;

                    _classCallCheck(this, Recorder);

                    this.config = {
                        bufferLen: 4096,
                        numChannels: 1,
                        mimeType: 'audio/wav'
                    };
                    this.recording = false;
                    this.callbacks = {
                        getBuffer: [],
                        exportWAV: []
                    };

                    Object.assign(this.config, cfg);
                    this.context = source.context;
                    this.node = (this.context.createScriptProcessor || this.context.createJavaScriptNode).call(this.context, this.config.bufferLen, this.config.numChannels, this.config.numChannels);

                    this.node.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
                        if (!_this.recording) return;

                        var buffer = [];
                        for (var channel = 0; channel < _this.config.numChannels; channel++) {
                            buffer.push(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel));
                        }
                        _this.worker.postMessage({
                            command: 'record',
                            buffer: buffer
                        });
                    };

                    source.connect(this.node);
                    this.node.connect(this.context.destination); //this should not be necessary

                    var self = {};
                    this.worker = new _inlineWorker2.default(function() {
                        var recLength = 0,
                            recBuffers = [],
                            sampleRate = undefined,
                            numChannels = undefined;

                        self.onmessage = function(e) {
                            switch (e.data.command) {
                                case 'init':
                                    init(e.data.config);
                                    break;
                                case 'record':
                                    record(e.data.buffer);
                                    break;
                                case 'exportWAV':
                                    exportWAV(e.data.type);
                                    break;
                                case 'getBuffer':
                                    getBuffer();
                                    break;
                                case 'clear':
                                    clear();
                                    break;
                            }
                        };

                        function init(config) {
                            sampleRate = config.sampleRate;
                            numChannels = config.numChannels;
                            initBuffers();
                        }

                        function record(inputBuffer) {
                            for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                                recBuffers[channel].push(inputBuffer[channel]);
                            }
                            recLength += inputBuffer[0].length;
                        }

                        function exportWAV(type) {
                            var buffers = [];
                            for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                                buffers.push(mergeBuffers(recBuffers[channel], recLength));
                            }
                            var interleaved = undefined;
                            if (numChannels === 2) {
                                interleaved = interleave(buffers[0], buffers[1]);
                            } else {
                                interleaved = buffers[0];
                            }
                            var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
                            var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], {
                                type: type
                            });

                            self.postMessage({
                                command: 'exportWAV',
                                data: audioBlob
                            });
                        }

                        function getBuffer() {
                            var buffers = [];
                            for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                                buffers.push(mergeBuffers(recBuffers[channel], recLength));
                            }
                            self.postMessage({
                                command: 'getBuffer',
                                data: buffers
                            });
                        }

                        function clear() {
                            recLength = 0;
                            recBuffers = [];
                            initBuffers();
                        }

                        function initBuffers() {
                            for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                                recBuffers[channel] = [];
                            }
                        }

                        function mergeBuffers(recBuffers, recLength) {
                            var result = new Float32Array(recLength);
                            var offset = 0;
                            for (var i = 0; i < recBuffers.length; i++) {
                                result.set(recBuffers[i], offset);
                                offset += recBuffers[i].length;
                            }
                            return result;
                        }

                        function interleave(inputL, inputR) {
                            var length = inputL.length + inputR.length;
                            var result = new Float32Array(length);

                            var index = 0,
                                inputIndex = 0;

                            while (index < length) {
                                result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex];
                                result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex];
                                inputIndex++;
                            }
                            return result;
                        }

                        function floatTo16BitPCM(output, offset, input) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset += 2) {
                                var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
                                output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
                            }
                        }

                        function writeString(view, offset, string) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                                view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
                            }
                        }

                        function encodeWAV(samples) {
                            var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
                            var view = new DataView(buffer);

                            /* RIFF identifier */
                            writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
                            /* RIFF chunk length */
                            view.setUint32(4, 36 + samples.length * 2, true);
                            /* RIFF type */
                            writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
                            /* format chunk identifier */
                            writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
                            /* format chunk length */
                            view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
                            /* sample format (raw) */
                            view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
                            /* channel count */
                            view.setUint16(22, numChannels, true);
                            /* sample rate */
                            view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
                            /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
                            view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
                            /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
                            view.setUint16(32, numChannels * 2, true);
                            /* bits per sample */
                            view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
                            /* data chunk identifier */
                            writeString(view, 36, 'data');
                            /* data chunk length */
                            view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

                            floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

                            return view;
                        }
                    }, self);

                    this.worker.postMessage({
                        command: 'init',
                        config: {
                            sampleRate: this.context.sampleRate,
                            numChannels: this.config.numChannels
                        }
                    });

                    this.worker.onmessage = function(e) {
                        var cb = _this.callbacks[e.data.command].pop();
                        if (typeof cb == 'function') {
                            cb(e.data.data);
                        }
                    };
                }

                _createClass(Recorder, [{
                    key: 'record',
                    value: function record() {
                        this.recording = true;
                    }
                }, {
                    key: 'stop',
                    value: function stop() {
                        this.recording = false;
                    }
                }, {
                    key: 'clear',
                    value: function clear() {
                        this.worker.postMessage({
                            command: 'clear'
                        });
                    }
                }, {
                    key: 'getBuffer',
                    value: function getBuffer(cb) {
                        cb = cb || this.config.callback;
                        if (!cb) throw new Error('Callback not set');

                        this.callbacks.getBuffer.push(cb);

                        this.worker.postMessage({
                            command: 'getBuffer'
                        });
                    }
                }, {
                    key: 'exportWAV',
                    value: function exportWAV(cb, mimeType) {
                        mimeType = mimeType || this.config.mimeType;
                        cb = cb || this.config.callback;
                        if (!cb) throw new Error('Callback not set');

                        this.callbacks.exportWAV.push(cb);

                        this.worker.postMessage({
                            command: 'exportWAV',
                            type: mimeType
                        });
                    }
                }], [{
                    key: 'forceDownload',
                    value: function forceDownload(blob, filename) {
                        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
                        var link = window.document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = url;
                        link.download = filename || 'output.wav';
                        var click = document.createEvent("Event");
                        click.initEvent("click", true, true);
                        link.dispatchEvent(click);
                    }
                }]);

                return Recorder;
            })();

            exports.default = Recorder;

        }, {
            "inline-worker": 3
        }],
        3: [function(require, module, exports) {
            "use strict";

            module.exports = require("./inline-worker");
        }, {
            "./inline-worker": 4
        }],
        4: [function(require, module, exports) {
            (function(global) {
                "use strict";

                var _createClass = (function() {
                    function defineProperties(target, props) {
                        for (var key in props) {
                            var prop = props[key];
                            prop.configurable = true;
                            if (prop.value) prop.writable = true;
                        }
                        Object.defineProperties(target, props);
                    }
                    return function(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
                        if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
                        if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
                        return Constructor;
                    };
                })();

                var _classCallCheck = function(instance, Constructor) {
                    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
                        throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
                    }
                };

                var WORKER_ENABLED = !!(global === global.window && global.URL && global.Blob && global.Worker);

                var InlineWorker = (function() {
                    function InlineWorker(func, self) {
                        var _this = this;

                        _classCallCheck(this, InlineWorker);

                        if (WORKER_ENABLED) {
                            var functionBody = func.toString().trim().match(/^function\s*\w*\s*\([\w\s,]*\)\s*{([\w\W]*?)}$/)[1];
                            var url = global.URL.createObjectURL(new global.Blob([functionBody], {
                                type: "text/javascript"
                            }));

                            return new global.Worker(url);
                        }

                        this.self = self;
                        this.self.postMessage = function(data) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                _this.onmessage({
                                    data: data
                                });
                            }, 0);
                        };

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            func.call(self);
                        }, 0);
                    }

                    _createClass(InlineWorker, {
                        postMessage: {
                            value: function postMessage(data) {
                                var _this = this;

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    _this.self.onmessage({
                                        data: data
                                    });
                                }, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    return InlineWorker;
                })();

                module.exports = InlineWorker;
            }).call(this, typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {})
        }, {}]
    }, {}, [1])(1)
});
```

Comment: try to remove 'use strict'

Comment: This is compiler output, and as such isn't really meant to be easily human-readable. Please post the original source code instead.

Comment: @LazarNikolic that is *terrible* advice... anyway as I said this is compiler output. Any change is just going to get overwritten next time the project gets compiled.

Comment: I've removed 'use strict' and it's still not working.

Comment: @JaredSmith Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @Joe this file was not written in it's current form by a human. It is the output of a compiler that took some other file written in a newer form of JavaScript (possibly with extensions like JSX) and rewrote it to a lowest-common-denominator version of JavaScript for old browsers. Where did it come from?

Comment: @Joe no, that file is again the compiled output of some other file. Post the code in that other file.

Comment: Actually, I think I know what part of the problem might be, the error says 'failed to compile'. It looks like you might be trying to compile a file that's already compiled. Where did you get it?

Comment: I'm trying to transform this project (https://github.com/aofdev/vue-pwa-speech) which is in Vue to React. The file which is giving me problems is https://github.com/aofdev/vue-pwa-speech/tree/master/static/js

Comment: @JaredSmith I've aligned the code. Better now?

Comment: @Joe no, not really, it has little to do with alignment. The problem is again, fundamentally, that you are trying to recompile an already compiled file. You will have to track down the original source of that file, or do something like put it in `public` and expose it's functionality through a global (I *strongly* recommend the former approach).

Comment: @JaredSmith Could you give me some advice on how to do it or recommend a tutorial?

Comment: All that @JaredSmith states applies - you should not compile an already compiled file. However the compile error seems to be a lint error (no-restricted-globals), possibly originated from `react-scripts`.

Answer (score -1):

These are linting errors that usually occurs when you're using `create-react-app` together with a local ESLint version. Using a local ESLint version together with a non-ejected `create-react-app` is not really supported.

If you remove your local ESLint packages and try to re-compile the project, you should not see these errors.

```
// First remove anything related to ESLint from package.json, then:
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

A project that is set up with `create-react-app` already has ESLint with a react configuration, it will do basic checks - no code style checks. React officially states that the style formatter [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) is a good tool to use for style formatting ([source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor)).

Comment: Removing eslint is not a solution, it should be whitelisted in eslint rule instead

Comment: @ShirshenduBhowmick I'm not suggesting to remove ESLint, but rather let CRA handle the linting, instead of including two conflicting versions.